# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, difference on desktop and notebook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this odd issue. I'm trying to code my Portfolio in ReactJS and I have a desktop and notebook. I'm uploading my code to my GitHub repository.

On my desktop, the code runs super fine and I don't get any error message, now if I clone my repository in my notebook, in the console doesn't appear any error but in the browser localhost:3000, I keep receiving this error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" from any part of code that I am mapping.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { Container, Columns, Title } from "./ProjectPortfolioElements";
import Card from "../Projects/Card";
import desktopMockup from "../../assets/projects/modern-browser-mockup.png";

import dictionary from "../Dictionary/dictionary";
import { LanguageContext } from "../../App";

function ProjectPortfolio() {
  const [language] = useContext(LanguageContext);

  return (
    <>
      {dictionary[language].map(({ project }) => (
        <>
          <Title>
            <h1>{project}</h1>
          </Title>
          <Container>
            <Columns>
              <Card
                image={desktopMockup}
                title="Logistic Website"
                description="This website was fully done with ReactJS"
              />
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
              <Card
                image={desktopMockup}
                title="Logistic Website"
                description="This website was fully done with ReactJS"
              />
            </Columns>
          </Container>{" "}
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default ProjectPortfolio;
```

I really don't have an idea what can be. The console is fine, my desktop is fine and my notebook doesn't run.

Comment: Could you attach LanguageContext code?

Comment: What is `dictionary` and what is `language` values? The error is saying that `dictionary[language]` is undefined for some combination of values.

Comment: dictionary is a JS file that I'm using to translate my website in 4 languages. 
language is the useState that I am exporting from App.js

Comment: The thing is, right now I get 0 errors on my desktop, and even when I clone the repo in my notebook, the console is clean, with no errors, just the browser is informing me that map is undefined. So I am super confused.

Comment: Could you please show how do you detect language?

Comment: Through the menu. I have 4 flags on the top right side, when I click, it changes the language.

I passed the piece of code here on plunkler because it is quite big: https://plnkr.co/edit/cOd4B1biETAAYOgF?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: It would just be easier to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code causing the problem. Can you now also share `dictionary` and `LanguageContext`? I suspect that `language` is undefined on the initial render. That or it's a value you don't have specified in the dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I tried my best to share the simplest component here.

Here is the dictionary: https://github.com/drrh12/Personal-Website/blob/main/src/components/Dictionary/dictionary.js

Here is the LanguageContext: https://github.com/drrh12/Personal-Website/blob/main/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultLanguage` is `"br"` if there is nothing stored in local storage. I suspect you are hitting this default value on the laptop since you've stated just cloning the project and it's likely not run to be able to set a language into localStorage.

```
const defaultLanguage = "br"; // <-- default
export const LanguageContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState(() => {
    const langFromLocalStorage = window.localStorage.getItem("lang");

    return langFromLocalStorage
      ? langFromLocalStorage
      : defaultLanguage; // <-- default if nothing in localStorage
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("lang", language);
  }, [language]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LanguageContext.Provider value={[language, setLanguage]}>
        <Main></Main>
      </LanguageContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I suggest changing `defaultLanguage` to one of `"en"`, `"ptbr"`, `"jp"`, or `"ru"`.

And/or as an extra guard, use Optional Chaining operator on the `dictionary[language]` value in case some other language is somehow stored in localStorage that isn't a key into the dictionary.

```
dictionary?.[language]?.map(......)
```

Comment: Drew, you are a genius! Thank you a lot!